# Git Checkout not showing new files in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

My friend has created a new branch. Let's call it "branch2". I'm currently on master. I typed `git checkout branch2` in Bash. I then type `git pull`.

I get the following message:

```
Unpacking objects: 100% (28/28), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/***/***
 * [new branch]      Parse_T1   -> origin/Parse_T1
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> Parse_T1
```

I don't want to ruin anything or merge anything. I just want to switch to that branch and see the updated files in IntelliJ. What should I do? Ugh, CLIs... This is why I love Mercurial.

Comment: Has your friend pushed his branch to the repository already?

Comment: Also there are several Git tools that aren't CLIs (although I greatly prefer the command line for Git, myself.)

Comment: I'd like to get better at the CLI. And yes, he has pushed the branch. I see the files in bitbucket but I want to switch and then update the files in IntelliJ via Bash. Basically, the files in my IDE don't change so I can't work on the new branch...

Comment: Ah but if you run, say `ls` you see the changed/new files?  I'm trying to isolate this to either your IDE or Git.

Comment: ``'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`` Where should I be typing this?

Comment: Uhm, which OS is this? I assumed a Unix-based system, which seems to be wrong.  Maybe `dir` for Windows?

Comment: Hah, yeah. Corporate IT Java web app running on Oracle, and Windows. Okay so I'm ``dir``ing into it and I still see the files from the the original master branch I was on, even after checking out and pulling from ``branch2``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134811/discussion-between-blackvegetable-and-santafebound).

Comment: We solved the problem together. The OP has agreed to write up the solution as a self-answer when he can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all get rid of any un-committed changes in the current branch. Then do the followings.

- You should first do '`git fetch`'. Now only your local repository knows about any new branches pushed into origin.
- Then just try '`git checkout branch2`' . It will make a ***local*** branch called 'branch2' which contains latest changes in origin/branch2. And you will be switched into local/branch2 automatically. :))